# google refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to google drive.but when i upload for the first time it works fine after a while I get refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

I am following this tutorial
[Laravel 9 Google Drive File Upload/Store Tutorial.](https://www.webappfix.com/post/laravel-9-google-drive-file-upload-store-tutorial.html)

I have searched Google and other answers on stack overflow as well most of them said that I have to add `$gClient->setAccessType("offline");` still after adding that I get the error

I have already tried these answers

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67503460/refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccesstoken)

[StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111931/google-api-client-refresh-token-must-be-passed-in-or-set-as-part-of-setaccesst)

```
    public function googleDriveFilePpload($company_id)
    {
$gClient = new \Google_Client();

        $gClient->setApplicationName('Application Name'); // ADD YOUR AUTH2 APPLICATION NAME (WHEN YOUR GENERATE SECRATE KEY)
        $gClient->setClientId('My CLient ID'); //Client ID
        $gClient->setClientSecret('My Secret ID'); //Secret ID
        $gClient->setRedirectUri(route('google.login'));
        $gClient->setDeveloperKey('API KEY'); //Google Project API Key
        $gClient->setScopes(array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        ));

        $gClient->setAccessType("offline");

        $gClient->setApprovalPrompt("force");


        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($gClient);

        $user = APIsTokens::where('siteName', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->first();
        $gClient->setAccessToken(json_decode($user->token, true));

        if ($gClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $refreshTokenSaved = $gClient->getRefreshToken();
            $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);
            $updatedAccessToken = $gClient->getAccessToken();
            $updatedAccessToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;
            $gClient->setAccessToken($updatedAccessToken);
            $user->access_token = $updatedAccessToken;
            $user->save();
        }

        $item = BackupHistory::where('Company_id', $company_id)->latest()->first();

        $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
            'name' => 'Database Backup',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
        ));

        $folder = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

        printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $folder->id);

        $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name' => $item->name, 'parents' => array($folder->id)));

        $result = $service->files->create($file, array(

            'data' => file_get_contents(storage_path('app/databaseBackup/' . $company_id . '/' . $item->name)),
            'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        ));
        return redirect('backup');
    }
```